# submitToRemote not working in Grails

Tags: grails

I'm still new to Grails so please bear with me. 
I have this on my GSP

```
<div class = "reviewForm">
     <g:render template="reviewForm"/>
 </g:if>

<div class="actions">
    <g:submitToRemote url="[controller:'game', action:'editReview']" update="reviewForm" value="Edit"/>
</div>
```

What I want to happen is when I click the button I want the reviewForm template to be changed to the editReview.gsp where the content of the review is displayed so I can edit the content. as of now my editReview.gsp is just empty I just want to see the form changed but it doesn't

I had my editReview action log.println to make sure if it goes in the action and it did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying it and found  `Rather than class we must be using id field to specify replacement div which will contain the data received from AJAX request.`

See you code modified below:

```
<div id= "reviewForm">
     <g:render template="reviewForm"/>
 </g:if>

<div class="actions">
    <g:submitToRemote url="[controller:'game', action:'editReview']" update="reviewForm" value="Edit"/>
</div>
```

More you can read grails docs [here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.7/ref/Tags/submitToRemote.html) for same.

Last but not least `submitToRemote` also provide some good events like before, after and many more to specify JS functions to be called.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help!